# fetching distance and driving time between two places in python not working for negative coordinates

Tags: python, maps

I am trying to fetch the distance and driving time between two places using python. The below code works however its not giving any response for negative coordinates. Kindly help me understand where i am going wrong.

```
import simplejson, urllib
orig_coord = orig_lat, orig_lng
dest_coord = dest_lat, dest_lng
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))
result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps' documentation says that you have to remove spaces between coordinates.

Right now, your url looks like this, because you are simply passing a tuple to the format function:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=(-27.598156, -67.531324)&destinations=(-30.099782, -60.236402)&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false
```

While it should look like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-27.598156,-67.531324&destinations=-30.099782,-60.236402&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false
```

You will have to make some changes to your url generation code to actually process the tuple and generate your needed string.

```
import requests
orig_coord = orig_lat, orig_lng
dest_coord = dest_lat, dest_lng
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={}&destinations={}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(",".join(map(str, orig_coord)),",".join(map(str, dest_coord)))
result = requests.get(url).json()
# evaluate the result here
```